# How do I fix this SQL syntax error, I cannot find it

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO ******_sports_teams (******_team_id,
>   ******_content_type_id, ******' at line 2

That is the error I get to this script;

The stars cover the name of the company I work for that I cannot release, but they are all the same word that I know is spelled correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM `******_sports_teams` WHERE 1

INSERT INTO ******_sports_teams 
 (******_team_id, ******_content_type_id, ******_content_type_desc, 
  ******_sport_name, ******_sport_confernece, ******_sport_division, 
  ******_sport_city, ******_sport_team)

VALUES
(1,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Atlantic','Boston','Celtics'),
(2,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Atlantic','Brooklyn','Nets'),
(3,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Atlantic','Newy York','Knicks'),
(4,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Atlantic','Philedelphia','76ers'),
(5,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Atlantic','Toronto','Raptors'),
(6,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Central','Chicago','Bulls'),
(7,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Central','Cleveland','Cavaliers'),
(8,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Central','Detriot','Pistons'),
(9,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Central','Indiana','Pacers'),
(10,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Central','Milwaukee','Bucks'),
(11,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Southeast','Atlanta','Hawks'),
(12,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Southeast','Charlotte','Hornets'),
(13,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Southeast','Miami','Heat'),
(14,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Southeast','Orlando','Magic'),
(15,4,'Sports','NBA','Eastern','Southeast','Washington','Wizards'),
(16,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Southwest','Dallas','Mavericks'),
(17,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Southwest','Houston','Rockets'),
(18,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Southwest','Memphis','Grizzlies'),
(19,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Southwest','New Orleans','Pelicans'),
(20,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Southwest','San Antonio','Spurs'),
(21,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Northwest','Denver','Nuggets'),
(22,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Northwest','Minnesota','Timber Wolves'),
(23,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Northwest','Oaklohoma City','Thunder'),
(24,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Northwest','Portland','Trail Blazers'),
(25,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Northwest','Utah','Jazz'),
(26,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Pacific','Golden State','Warriors'),
(27,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Pacific','Los Ageles','Clippers'),
(28,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Pacific','Los Ageles','Lakers'),
(29,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Pacific','Pheonix','Suns'),
(30,4,'Sports','NBA','Western','Pacific','Sacremento','Kings'),
(31,4,'Sports','MLB','American','East','Tampa Bay','Rays'),
(32,4,'Sports','MLB','American','East','New York','Yankees'),
(33,4,'Sports','MLB','American','East','Baltimore','Orioles'),
(34,4,'Sports','MLB','American','East','Toronto','Blue Jays'),
(35,4,'Sports','MLB','American','East','Boston','Red Socks'),
(36,4,'Sports','MLB','American','Central','Kansas City','Royals'),
(37,4,'Sports','MLB','American','Central','Minnesota','Twins'),
(38,4,'Sports','MLB','American','Central','Detriot','Tigers'),
(39,4,'Sports','MLB','American','Central','Cleveland','Indians'),
(40,4,'Sports','MLB','American','Central','Chicago','White Sox'),
(41,4,'Sports','MLB','American','West','Houston','Astros'),
(42,4,'Sports','MLB','American','West','Texas','Rangers'),
(43,4,'Sports','MLB','American','West','Los Ageles','Angels'),
(44,4,'Sports','MLB','American','West','Seattle','Mariners'),
(45,4,'Sports','MLB','American','West','Oakland','Athletics'),
(46,4,'Sports','MLB','National','East','New York','Mets'),
(47,4,'Sports','MLB','National','East','Washington','Nationals').
(48,4,'Sports','MLB','National','East','Atlanta','Braves'),
(49,4,'Sports','MLB','National','East','Philedelphia','Phillies'),
(50,4,'Sports','MLB','National','East','Miami','Marlins'),
(51,4,'Sports','MLB','National','Central','St. Louis','Cardinals'),
(52,4,'Sports','MLB','National','Central','Pittsburg','Pirates'),
(53,4,'Sports','MLB','National','Central','Chicago','Cubs'),
(54,4,'Sports','MLB','National','Central','Cincinnati','Reds'),
(55,4,'Sports','MLB','National','Central','Milwaukee','Brewers'),
(56,4,'Sports','MLB','National','West','Los Ageles','Dodgers'),
(57,4,'Sports','MLB','National','West','San Francisco','Giants'),
(58,4,'Sports','MLB','National','West','Arizona','Diamondbacks'),
(59,4,'Sports','MLB','National','West','San Diego','Padres'),
(60,4,'Sports','MLB','National','West','Colorado','Rockies'),
(61,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','East','Dallas','Cowboys'),
(62,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','East','New York','Giants'),
(63,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','East','Philedelphia','Eagles'),
(64,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','East','Washington','Redskins'),
(65,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','West','Arizona','Cardinals'),
(66,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','West','San Francisco','49ers'),
(67,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','West','Seattle','Seahawks'),
(68,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','West','St. Louis','Rams'),
(69,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','North','Chicago','Bears'),
(70,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','North' ,'Detriot','Lions'),
(71,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','North' ,'Green Bay','Packers'),
(72,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','North' ,'Minnesota','Vikings'),
(73,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','South','Atlanta','Falcons'),
(74,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','South', 'Carolina','Panthers'),
(75,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','South','New Orleans','Saints'),
(76,4,'Sports','NFL','NFC','South','Tampa Bay','Buccaneers'),
(77,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','East','Buffalo','Bills'),
(78,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','East','Miami','Dolphins'),
(79,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','East','New England','Patriots'),
(80,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','East','New York','Jets'),
(81,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','West','Denver','Broncos'),
(82,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','West','Kansas City','Chiefs'),
(83,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','West','Oakland','Raiders'),
(84,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','West','San Diego','Chargers'),
(85,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','North' ,'Baltimore','Ravens'),
(86,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','North' ,'Cleveland','Browns'),
(87,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','North','Pittsburg','Steelers'),
(88,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','North' ,'Cincinnati','Bengals'),
(89,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','South','Houston','Texans'),
(90,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','South','Indianapolis','Colts'),
(91,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','South','Jacksonville','Jaguars'),
(92,4,'Sports','NFL','AFC','South','Tennessee','Titans'),
(93,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Central','Chicago','Blackhawks'),
(94,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Central','Colorado','Avalanche'),
(95,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Central','Dallas','Stars'),
(96,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Central','Minnesota','Wild'),
(97,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Central','St. Louis','Blues'),
(98,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Central','Winnipeg','Jets'),
(99,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Central','Nashville','Predators'),
(100,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Pacific','Anaheim' ,'Ducks'),
(101,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Pacific','Arizona','Coyotes'),
(102,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Pacific','Clagary','Flames'),
(103,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Pacific','Edmonton','Oilers'),
(104,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Pacific','Los Ageles','Kings'),
(105,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Pacific','San Jose','Sharks'),
(106,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Pacific','Vancouver','Canucks'),
(107,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Atlantic','Boston','Bruins'),
(108,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Atlantic','Buffalo','Sabres'),
(109,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Atlantic','Detriot','Red Wings'),
(110,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Atlantic','Florida','Panthers'),
(111,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Atlantic','Montreal','Canadiens'),
(112,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Atlantic','Ottawa','Senators'),
(113,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Atlantic','Tampa Bay','Lightning'),
(114,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Atlantic','Toronto','Maple Leafs'),
(115,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Metropolitan','Corolina','Hurricanes'),
(116,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Metropolitan','Columbus','Blue Jackets'),
(117,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Metropolitan','New Jersey','Devils'),
(118,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Metropolitan','New York','Islanders'),
(119,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Metropolitan','New York','Rangers'),
(120,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Metropolitan','Philedelphia','Flyers'),
(121,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Metropolitan','Pittsburg','Penguins'),
(122,4,'Sports','NHL','NHL','Metropolitan','Washington','Capitals')
```

Comment: I checked on W3 kids and it said that I need the values

Comment: Could you format this for us please buddy, edit->hilight->click {}

Comment: You are missed `;` between two queries :)

Comment: What are the two queries, I am sorry I am fairly new at working with databases

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your error message show us, that two queries does not separated with `;`

Just remove `Select` query, or add `;` after it.

Then, double check syntax, or read next error message. You have points instead of comma somewhere.

---

Your first query retrieve all data from the table. It's:

```
SELECT * FROM `******_sports_teams` WHERE 1
```

It should terminated with semicolon before you call next (`INSERT`) query

Comment: Downvoters, please help me to improve this answer. Just left a comment what's wrong here...

Answer (score 2):

you have a dot (`.`) instead of a comma (`,`) at the end of the line with ID 47:

```
(47,4,'Sports','MLB','National','East','Washington','Nationals').
```

Change it to

```
(47,4,'Sports','MLB','National','East','Washington','Nationals'),
```

Comment: `(47,4,'Sports','MLB','National','East','Washington','Nationals')***.***`

Comment: Thank you, however even with the period changed to a comma the error persists informing that the syntax problem is in the second line

Answer (score 0):

You have a period at the end of this line:

```
(47,4,'Sports','MLB','National','East','Washington','Nationals').
```

It should be a comma